# Python function explanation

Tags: python

What does this part of program do (found on [Nubela's guthub](https://github.com/nubela/nus-cs5215-constraint-programming/blob/master/assignment2/solver.py))?

```
def product(*args, **kwds):
    """
    for py2.6< support (they lack itertools lib)
    - http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations
    """
    pools = map(tuple, args) * kwds.get('repeat', 1)
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod)
```

And later in program:

```
list(set((product(*[range(2) for _ in range(length)]))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It implements [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for backwards compatibility. See the documentation for `product`:

> itertools.product(*iterables[, repeat])
>
> Cartesian product of input iterables.
>
> Equivalent to nested for-loops in a generator expression. For example, product(A, B) returns the same as ((x,y) for x in A for y in
>   B).
>
> The nested loops cycle like an odometer with the rightmost element advancing on every iteration. This pattern creates a lexicographic
>   ordering so that if the input’s iterables are sorted, the product
>   tuples are emitted in sorted order.
>
> To compute the product of an iterable with itself, specify the number of repetitions with the optional repeat keyword argument. For
>   example, product(A, repeat=4) means the same as product(A, A, A, A).
>
> This function is equivalent to the following code, except that the actual implementation does not build up intermediate results in
>   memory:
>
> ```
> def product(*args, **kwds):
>     # product('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy Dx Dy
>     # product(range(2), repeat=3) --> 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111
>     pools = map(tuple, args) * kwds.get('repeat', 1)
>     result = [[]]
>     for pool in pools:
>         result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
>     for prod in result:
>         yield tuple(prod)
> ```

Note how the code in the documentation matches what you found.

I don't understand why they put in the doc a reference to `itertools.permutations`...
the code:

```
list(set((product(*[range(2) for _ in range(length)]))))
```

AFAIK it is equivalent to:

```
list(product(*[range(2) for _ in range(length)]))
```

Which simply computes the product of `length` `range(2)` iterables.

Comment: Yes, exactly to compute permutations. It's a nonogram solver after all.